# how to conect a ssd drive to RP3 instead of using a SD card?

Tags: boot

I have a SSD drive that is a boot drive of Daphile programm(it works well in a computer as a music server), now i want to mount it to RP3 as a main booting instead of using a SD card. So is it OK and how to connect to RP3?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Rasbperry doesn't support boot from USB afaik.</s> Apparently Raspberry supports USB boot, see: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Daphile only offers 64-bit x86 and 32-bit x86 images - no ARM images, so you won't be able to boot that on your ARM device.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

No.

### Explanation:

[The Daphile website](https://daphile.com/) states the following:

> Daphile ISO images:
>
> 64-bit x86 – recommended:  daphile-19.12-x86_64.iso
> md5sum: a2ec4a9fb5bd1e1f57a35866bb6b9e17
> 32-bit x86: daphile-19.12-i486.iso
> md5sum: 4be5512af9e104a86cd3794da1f24bf4
> 64-bit x86 with realtime kernel: daphile-19.12-x86_64-rt.iso
> md5sum: c29ccaec01423501f01dc0e8c84dadc8

The *key phrase* here is [**`x86`**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) This means that the software will run on processors that are compatible with Intel's X86 architecture. Your Raspberry Pi (*all* Raspberry Pis as of this date) uses the [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) which is incompatible with the x86 [instruction set.]

Note however that it's *entirely possible* to modify the source code for *Daphile*, and re-compile it to run on an ARM-based device such as Raspberry Pi. That is what was done to create the [*Raspbian* OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) that powers the Raspberry Pi: the Raspbian developers began with some variant of the [Debian distribution](https://www.debian.org/), made (rather extensive) modifications to it, and compiled this modified code to run on an ARM processor.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi 3B+

The Raspberry Pi 3B+ supports USB mass storage boot out of the box.

See the link below

[USB mass storage boot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md)

[USB host boot mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/host.md)